# Make part of a caption bold in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Based on the code below how can I make `Source` bold? I tried the following but, it made the whole caption bold.

Current Output:

[image]

Data (`pop_hisp_df`):

```
structure(list(age_group = c("<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", 
"25  -  34", "35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", 
"75  -  84", "85 +", "<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", "25  -  34", 
"35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", "75  -  84", 
"85 +"), Type = c("Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", 
"Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females"), Value = c(-6, -13, -13, -15, -17, -15, 
-11, -6, -3, -1, 6, 12, 12, 14, 16, 15, 12, 7, 4, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
# Plot
    gg_pop_gen = ggplot(pop_gen_df, aes(x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type))  +
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_gen_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") + 
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_gen_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") + 
      #geom_text(aes(label = paste0(abs(Value), "%"))) +
      #scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")) +          # CHANGE
      scale_y_continuous(
        limits=c(-20,20),
        breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
        labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")
      ) + 
      scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#ED5151", "Males"="#6B6BD6"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
      ggtitle("TOTAL POPULATION BY AGE AND GENDER") +
      labs(x = "AGE GROUPS", y = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", fill = "Gender") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom") +
      coord_flip()
    
    # Interactive
    ggplotly(gg_pop_gen) %>% 
      layout(
        legend = list(
          orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
          title = list(text = '')
        )
      ) %>%
      reverse_legend_labels() %>% 
      layout(margin = list(l = 0, r = 50, b = 100, t = 50),
             annotations = list(x = 1, y = -0.3, text = "<b>Figure3<b/>: Data for Figure 3 was reteieved from: \n U.S. Census Bureau, American Community 5-Year Estimates",
                                xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow = F, 
                                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                                font = list(size = 10)))
```

Comment: Try closing the HTML tag with `</b>` instead of `<b/>`

Comment: Yep that worked thank you, how can I make the caption left aligned with plot?

Comment: Try using `align = 'left'` in your list of `annotations`?

Comment: That didn't work (it placed the caption in the middle of plot 2) but changing  `x = 0.3` worked.